# Relationship between continuous outcome variable (with many zeroes) and predictors using SAS

Tags: sas, continuous

I have a continuous dependant variable (volume of chemical) with lots of values as 0 and a bunch of continuous and categorical predictors. I want to examine the relationship between predictors and the volume of chemicals. I was thinking of using multiple linear regression but many values in the outcome variable are 0. So, I am not sure how I should proceed.
I am using SAS.

Comment: Can you give more details on the distribution of your dependent variable? The range, n, mean, sd, histogram? Anyway, you may try a log(y+0.01) transformation of yoúr dependent variable. Add 0.01 and take the log of it. Run a histogram before and after. Check if gets close to a normal distribution

Comment: Also, please provide the percentage of zeros from your total sample (n)

Comment: Nobs = 4842, min = 0, median = 0, max = 426.03, mean = 2.78625 SD=19.0578. 93% values are zero.

Comment: I never modelled anything like it. But [this paper might help](https://www.journals.uchicago.edu/doi/full/10.1086/701235?mobileUi=0&) . Also you may try to post your question in cross-validated: a community for statistical models

Comment: You could do a so called "two-stage" modeling, i.e. (i) a model to predict whether the response variable y is 0 or >0 and (ii) a model to predict the continuous response value for the cases with y > 0.
In case you have access to SAS Enterprise Miner, there is a node called Two-Stage model that does precisely this.

Comment: Thanks. I think two-stage model is the way to go.